# Make the background of image fade to the bottom using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a background image set up on my home page.

[image: Current Background State]

and for mobile as you see the image has a sharp cut i would like to have a background such as:

[image: Desired Effect]

so that background has a gradient fade till bottom is there a way to achieve this with css or designing and using a background that way is the best option?

Comment: CSS can't automatically detect the color of the image, however, if you know the color you want for each background, you could set a class on the `body` tag that would set a specific color depending on the image. This isn't a dynamic approach as you'd have to manually set the colors for each image.

Comment: Please update your question with actual CSS and related HTML so we can best assist you here

Answer (score 0):

Use body or container background (div)

```css
#container{
width:100%;
height:100vh;
background: rgb(252,161,120);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(252,161,120,1) 0%, rgba(247,147,101,1) 30%, rgba(246,123,71,1) 66%, rgba(244,102,42,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```